# Accessing fields from a proxied object

Tags: java, android, reflection, proxy, dalvik

I've run into an interesting problem while developing an ORM framework for Android. I'm using a library called [dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) for bytecode manipulation, which enables me to create proxies for persistent objects in order to implement lazy loading.

The proxied instance has an associated `InvocationHandler` such that when a method is called on the proxy, the `invoke` method is called on the `InvocationHandler`, which then calls the proxied object's respective method assuming it's been lazily loaded. Nothing too surprising -- it's just like Java's [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class but allows me to proxy actual classes instead of interfaces (see dexmaker's [ProxyBuilder](http://dexmaker.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/dexmaker/stock/ProxyBuilder.html)).

The part that's become problematic is that I also use reflection to retrieve field values from persistent objects and -- now that I've introduced lazy loading -- proxies. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
for (Field f : getPersistentFields(model.getClass()) {
    ...
    Object val = f.get(model); // model is either a persistent object or a proxy for one
    mapField(f, val, map);
}
```

This of course works for regular model instances, but for proxied instances, `f.get(model)` is not retrieving the proxied object's field value. Instead, it's returning the default value assigned in the class's constructor. The access on the proxy's field is not being intercepted obviously.

**My question is this:** is there any way I can intercept an access on a proxy's member variable made through reflection? If not, how can I retrieve the value of a proxy's field in a "reflection-like" way?

**One possible workaround** I'm thinking of would be to retrieve and then invoke the field's getter method using reflection, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct solution. This workaround, if it actually *works*, would require the object to have a getter method for all persistent fields -- a requirement that should typically be followed from an OO-design point of view but also forces more work onto the user of the framework.

I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: Are the fields still being modified? How?

Comment: The proxy fields are not modified.

Comment: Can you please elaborate somewhat on your design? Do the proxy classes represent the model or do they have a connection to the model object?

Comment: @Stefan: the proxies represent the model. Rather than loading an object's related models, they are initialized as proxies. Then, when a proxy is accessed, for example by invoking one of its methods, the `InvocationHandler` will intercept the method call, load the actual model object, and invoke the method on the newly loaded object.

Comment: A client always accesses the model invoking a method? This problem is restricted to the framework's internals?

Comment: @Stefan: it's completely internal to the framework. The lazy loading is, more or less, invisible to the client. For now, I've implemented the workaround I described above which works. I was wondering if there is perhaps a more sophisticated solution, or at least one which removes the need to handle proxies in a special manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to access the fields using setter/getters rather than using Field class. (I believe this is more than a workaround)

On the other hand, if you want to go with the direct field accessing approach. As far as I see there is no easy way to intercept field accesses. Please check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198164/bytecode-manipulation-to-intercept-setting-the-value-of-a-field). Altough the question is related with intercepting field modification rather than reading
the field, it may provide some insights and direction.

Comment: Thanks, vizier. I went ahead and implemented the first approach, using the getter methods to access the fields. It seemed like the most straightforward approach and it works quite well.