# Autowiring order NullPointerException

Tags: spring

See below code for more information. This throws a `NullPointerException` in `name()` method (marked with a comment below). My understanding is that Spring reads the `@Configuration` sequentially, so first autowires `namePrinter`, then `nameProvider`. Since `nameProvider` is used in `name()`, which in turn needs to be autowired for `NamePrinter` constructor, the NPE can be explained. I also know of two solutions:

- One is to make the order as expected by hand. I find this should be Spring's job.
- The other is to autowire by parameter, i.e.:

  ```
  @Bean
  public Name name(NameProvider nameProvider) {
     return nameProvider.getName();
  }
  ```

  I also feel this should be Spring's job and would like to avoid this in situations where there are many parameters - using `@Autowired` in configuration looks much more readable to me in these cases.

Some questions:

- With regard to the solution 2 above - why is Spring treating method parameters and autowired class variables differently?
- Are there legitimate reasons Spring doesn't order beans to be autowired by dependency order and instead opts for the source file definition order?
- Did you run into issues such as this? If so, how did you solve them in your particular cases? Hope I overlooked something here that can be useful

Versions:

- Java 1.7
- Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE

Code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

interface Name {
   String getName();
}

@Component
class NameProvider {
   public Name getName() {
      return new Name() {
         @Override
         public String getName() {
            return "Foo";
         }
      };
   }
}

@Component
class NamePrinter {
   private final Name name;

   @Autowired
   public NamePrinter(Name name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void print() {
      System.out.println(name.getName());
   }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { SpringAutowiringPrbConfig.class })
class SpringAutowiringPrbConfig {
   @Autowired
   private NamePrinter namePrinter;
   @Autowired
   private NameProvider nameProvider;

   @Bean
   public Name name() {
      return nameProvider.getName(); // NullPointerException here
   }
}

public class SpringAutowiringPrb {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
         SpringAutowiringPrbConfig.class);
      NamePrinter namePrinter = context.getBean(NamePrinter.class);
      namePrinter.print();
      context.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior :

This is kind of a circular example. Spring's `@Configuration` classes do resolve `@Autowired` targets before invoking `@Bean` methods. **However**, if part of the `@Autowired` resolution process requires a `@Bean` method to be invoked, then you have to be able to deal with it.

In your example, you have

```
@Autowired
private NamePrinter namePrinter;
@Autowired
private NameProvider nameProvider;
```

It seems, in this case (and this has to do with reflection and how `Field` objects are retrieved from a `Class` object), that Spring tries to resolve the `namePrinter` field first. To perform that resolution, Spring has to instantiate and initialize the `NamePrinter` bean. It will therefore invoke

```
@Autowired
public NamePrinter(Name name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

To do that, it needs a `Name` bean to inject into the constructor. To get that `Name` bean, it needs to invoke

```
@Bean
public Name name() {
   return nameProvider.getName(); // NullPointerException here
}
```

And were back here. `nameProvider` hasn't been processed yet and so is `null`.

You could look at the stack trace to see that Spring is in the process of autowiring something when the NPE occurs.

---

> With regard to the solution 2 above - why is Spring treating method
>   parameters and autowired class variables differently?

It doesn't really. When Spring needs to autowire

```
@Bean
public Name name(NameProvider nameProvider) {
   return nameProvider.getName();
}
```

it checks for a `NameProvider` bean definition and initializes the bean if one exists. It can then inject it into the constructor. Previously, it didn't have any hints about what objects may be used inside the method. Reflection, which Spring uses, cannot look at the body of a method. It can only look at its definition.

> Are there legitimate reasons Spring doesn't order beans to be
>   autowired by dependency order and instead opts for the source file
>   definition order?

Spring uses reflection to get `Field` objects of a `Class`.  In particular, it uses `Class#getDeclaredFields()` which states

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order.

So it was just (un)lucky that `namePrinter` came first.

> Did you run into issues such as this? If so, how did you solve them in
>   your particular cases? Hope I overlooked something here that can be
>   useful

Analyze your code and try to flesh out any circular dependencies. Consider using `@DependsOn`, though it won't help here.

There's also the option of ditching `@Component` (and its specializations) and doing everything wiht `@Bean` methods.

You could have

```
@Bean 
public NamePrinter namePrinter() {
    return new NamePrinter(name());
}

@Bean
public NameProvider nameProvider() {
    return new NameProvider();
}

@Bean
public Name name() {
    return nameProvider().getName();
}
```

This works because Spring creates a custom subclass (and instance) of your `@Configuration` class in which it can intercept the calls to `@Bean` methods, cache the result of the invocation, and provide that same result in all future invocations.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios! "Reflection, which Spring uses, cannot look at the body of a method." OK, that makes sense. In conjunction with the fact that intercepting field access is not something Java allows (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4207523/3821009)), I guess nothing Spring can do. Bummer... "Analyze your code and try to flesh out any circular dependencies." Note there are no circular dependencies here - NamePrinter depends on Name, which in turn depends on NameProvider, all straight. Except the above solutions, do you see anything simpler? If not, I'll do as above and be done.

Comment: @levantpied Sorry, I meant _circular dependencies_ as in something that causes this issue. There is an alternative (which I've added as an edit), where, instead of using `@Component` and component-scanning, you declare your beans explicitly with `@Bean`. Note that your other solution (method parameters) is essentially the same. You should always prefer to do method and constructor injection over field injection.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios - agree, this is similar to 2nd solution, though a bit more verbose. I think adding a parameter to @Bean-annotated method would be the most concise here.